# Codeigniter Cómo llamar a un determinado script en cada vista?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

soy nueva en esto de la programación web y estoy usando Codeigniter como framework. Mi problema es que necesito llamar un determinado script para una vista determinada. Es decir, quiero hacer mi código más eficiente, al llamar sólo a los scripts que sean necesarios: por ejemplo, llamar al script de TinyMCE sólo en la vista de "Crear nueva publicación" del blog que estoy haciendo. Algunas ideas o sugerencias?
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente has un llamado desde tu controlador al script y los seteas a la vista, ejemplo:

```
// Tu Controlador
Class MI_CONTROLADOR extends CI_Controller{

  // La funcion del constructor

  public function index(){
    $data = (
        'content' => 'modulos/index',
        'scripts' => 'scripts/my_script.js'
    );

    $this->load->view('main', $data);
  }
}


// Main
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <content>
        if(isset($data['content'])){
          echo $data['content'];
        }
    </content>

  if(isset($data['scripts'])){
    <script src="'.$data['scripts'].'"></script>
  }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me sirvió. Muchas gracias!